my polyline is not working need assistant in checking what exactly is wrong
i am working on a Flutter map-based application that handles user requests by allowing them to set pickup, destination, and optionally drop-off markers on the map. The app then draws a polyline route between these markers to visually represent the path. However, my polyline route is not working as expected, and I can't identify the exact cause.
Current Functionality
The user taps on the map to set the pickup and destination markers.
These markers are displayed on the map, and their coordinates are stored in corresponding controllers.
After setting the markers, a polyline route is supposed to be drawn between the pickup and destination points using a mapping service Google Maps API
Observed Behavior
Markers are being placed correctly on the map.
The polyline route does not appear
Expected Behavior
A visible polyline should be drawn on the map, connecting the pickup and destination markers .
Possible Causes Considered
Incorrect handling of the polyline data or coordinates.
Issues with the mapping API response.
Problems in the Polyline widget configuration or adding it to the map.
have tried to check to no avail so i ask for assistance
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/models/surge_zone_model.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/services/location_search_service.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/services/map_service.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/utils/surge_calculator.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/widgets/bottom_info_sheet.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/widgets/drop_off_widget.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/providers/surge_provider.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/utils/map_utils.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/services/polyline.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/widgets/loading_indicator.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/widgets/map_widget_methods.dart';
import 'package:snaptow_map_with_surge/widgets/route_info_bottom_sheet.dart';

class NewMapWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewMapWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NewMapWidgetState createState() => _NewMapWidgetState();
}

class _NewMapWidgetState extends State<NewMapWidget> with MapWidgetMethods {
  late GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Position? _currentPosition;
  Marker? _pickupMarker;
  Marker? _destinationMarker;
  StreamSubscription<Position>? _positionStreamSubscription;
  bool _isTracking = false;
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String _loadingMessage = '';

  final TextEditingController _pickupController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _destinationController = TextEditingController();

  List<SurgeZoneModel> surgeZones = [];
  Set<Marker> surgeZoneMarkers = {};
  Set<Circle> _surgeZoneCircles = {};
  Set<Polyline> _polylines = {};

  BitmapDescriptor? _cachedMarkerIcon;
  Timer? _surgeUpdateTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeLocation();
    _loadSurgeZones();
    _startSurgeUpdates();
  }

  void _startSurgeUpdates() {
    _surgeUpdateTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 5), (timer) {
      _loadSurgeZones();
    });
  }

  Future<void> _initializeLocation() async {
    await _checkPermissions();
    await _getCurrentLocation();
    _startLocationTracking();
  }

  void _startLocationTracking() {
    _positionStreamSubscription = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
      locationSettings: const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
        distanceFilter: 10,
      ),
    ).listen((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        if (_isTracking) {
          _moveCameraToPosition(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));
        }
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _checkPermissions() async {
    bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      _showPermissionDialog('Please enable location services.');
      return;
    }

    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        _showPermissionDialog('Location permission is denied.');
        return;
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      _showPermissionDialog('Location permissions are permanently denied.');
      return;
    }
  }

  void _showPermissionDialog(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Permission Required'),
        content: Text(message),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: const Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      final position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        _isTracking = true;
      });
      _moveCameraToPosition(LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude));
    } catch (e) {
      _showError('Could not get current location: $e');
    }
  }

  void _showError(String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
    );
  }

  void _moveCameraToPosition(LatLng position) {
    _mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(position, 14.0));
  }

  Future<void> _setMarker(LatLng position, String title,
      {required String type}) async {
    final icon = await _createCustomMarkerIcon(type: type);

    setState(() {
      switch (type) {
        case 'pickup':
          _pickupMarker = Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId('pickup'),
            position: position,
            icon: icon,
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Pickup: $title'),
          );
          break;
        case 'destination':
          _destinationMarker = Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId('destination'),
            position: position,
            icon: icon,
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Destination: $title'),
          );
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  void _updateRouteIfComplete() {
    // Ensure both pickup and destination markers are set before drawing the route
    if (_pickupMarker != null && _destinationMarker != null) {
      if (_pickupMarker!.position != null &&
          _destinationMarker!.position != null) {
        // Only draw the route if both markers have positions
        _drawPolyline(_pickupMarker!.position, _destinationMarker!.position);
      } else {
        print('Markers have no valid position');
      }
    } else {
      print(
          'Pickup${_pickupMarker!.position} or destination${_destinationMarker!.position} marker is missing ');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _drawPolyline(LatLng start, LatLng end) async {
    try {
      // Fetch the polyline coordinates (e.g., from a routing API like Google Directions)
      List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = await getPolylines(start, end);
      setState(() {
        // Add the polyline to the map
        _polylines.add(
          Polyline(
            polylineId: PolylineId('${start.toString()}_${end.toString()}'),
            points: polylineCoordinates,
            color: AppColors.snaptowOfficialColour, // Use your app's color
            width: 5,
          ),
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      _showError('Could not draw route: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _createCustomMarkerIcon({String? type}) async {
    switch (type) {
      case 'destination':
        return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed);

      case 'pickup':
        return BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen);
      default:
        if (_cachedMarkerIcon != null) return _cachedMarkerIcon!;

        final pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
        final canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
        const size = 50.0;

        final paintBackground = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
        canvas.drawCircle(
            const Offset(size / 2, size / 2), size / 2, paintBackground);

        final image = await pictureRecorder
            .endRecording()
            .toImage(size.toInt(), size.toInt());
        final byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
        final bytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

        _cachedMarkerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes);
        return _cachedMarkerIcon!;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _loadSurgeZones() async {
    try {
      final surgeProvider = Provider.of<SurgeProvider>(context, listen: false);
      await surgeProvider.fetchSurgeZones();
      surgeZones = surgeProvider.surgeZones;
      _updateSurgeZoneVisualization();
    } catch (e) {
      _showError('Could not load surge zones: $e');
    }
  }

  void _updateSurgeZoneVisualization() {
    setState(() {
      surgeZoneMarkers = surgeZones.map((zone) {
        return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('surge_${zone.id}'),
          position: zone.region,
          icon:
              BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: 'Surge Zone ${zone.surgeMultiplier}x',
            snippet: 'Higher demand in this area',
          ),
        );
      }).toSet();

      _surgeZoneCircles = surgeZones.map((zone) {
        return Circle(
          circleId: CircleId('surge_${zone.id}'),
          center: zone.region,
          radius: zone.radius,
          fillColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
          strokeColor: Colors.red,
          strokeWidth: 2,
        );
      }).toSet();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _buildMap(),
        _buildSearchFields(_destinationController, _pickupController),
        if (_pickupMarker != null && _destinationMarker != null)
          _buildRouteInfo(),
        if (_isLoading) LoadingIndicator(message: _loadingMessage),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRouteInfo() {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      child: RouteInfoBottomSheet(
        pickup: _pickupMarker?.position,
        destination: _destinationMarker?.position,
        distance: _calculateDistance(),
        estimatedTime: _calculateEstimatedTime(),
        onRequestTow: _handleTowRequest,
      ),
    );
  }

  double? _calculateDistance() {
    if (_pickupMarker == null || _destinationMarker == null) return null;
    final mapService = MapService();
    double totalDistance = mapService.calculateDistance(
      _pickupMarker!.position,
      _destinationMarker!.position,
    );

    return totalDistance / 1000; // Convert to kilometers
  }

  double? _calculateEstimatedTime() {
    final distance = _calculateDistance();
    if (distance == null) return null;
    // Assume average speed of 40 km/h for tow trucks
    return (distance / 40) * 60; // Convert to minutes
  }

  void _handleTowRequest() {
    if (_pickupMarker == null || _destinationMarker == null) {
      _showError('Please select pickup and destination locations');
      return;
    }
    // TODO: Implement tow request handling
    _showError('Tow request functionality not implemented yet');
  }

  Widget _buildMap() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (controller) => _mapController = controller,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _currentPosition != null
                ? LatLng(
                    _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude)
                : const LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 14.0,
          ),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          markers: {
            if (_pickupMarker != null) _pickupMarker!,
            if (_destinationMarker != null) _destinationMarker!,
            ...surgeZoneMarkers,
          },
          circles: _surgeZoneCircles,
          polylines: _polylines,
          onTap: (LatLng position) => _handleMapTap(position),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 40,
          left: 16,
          right: 16,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _pickupController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter pickup location',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 14),
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (value) =>
                      _handleLocationSearch(value, 'pickup'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
              Card(
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _destinationController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter destination',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 14),
                  ),
                  onSubmitted: (value) =>
                      _handleLocationSearch(value, 'destination'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 16,
          right: 16,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _getCurrentLocation,
            child: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _handleLocationSearch(String query, String type) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
      _loadingMessage = 'Searching location...';
    });
    try {
      final locationService = LocationSearchService();
      final suggestions = await locationService.searchLocation(query);

      if (suggestions.isNotEmpty) {
        final selectedPlace = await showDialog<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Select Location'),
            content: SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: suggestions.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(suggestions[index]['description']),
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context, suggestions[index]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );

        if (selectedPlace != null) {
          final location = await locationService.getLocationCoordinates(
            selectedPlace['place_id'],
          );
          _setMarker(location, selectedPlace['description'], type: type);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _showError('Error searching location: $e');
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _handleMapTap(LatLng position) {
    // Check which marker to set based on the type of marker needed
    if (_pickupMarker == null) {
      // Set the pickup marker
      _setMarker(position, 'Pickup Location', type: 'pickup');
      _pickupController.text =
          'Pickup: ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}';
    } else if (_destinationMarker == null) {
      // Set the destination marker
      _setMarker(position, 'Destination Location', type: 'destination');
      _destinationController.text =
          'Destination: ${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}';
    } else {
      // If both markers are already set, either reset or show an error
      _showError('Pickup and destination locations are already set.');
    }

    // Update the route if both markers are set
    _updateRouteIfComplete();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _positionStreamSubscription?.cancel();
    _surgeUpdateTimer?.cancel();
    _pickupController.dispose();
    _destinationController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void drawPolyline(LatLng start, LatLng end) {
    _drawPolyline(start, end);
  }

  @override
  Marker? getDestinationMarker() => _destinationMarker;

  @override
  Marker? getPickupMarker() => _pickupMarker;

  @override
  void updateDestinationMarker(Marker marker) {
    setState(() {
      _destinationMarker = marker;
    });
  }

  @override
  void updatePickupMarker(Marker marker) {
    setState(() {
      _pickupMarker = marker;
    });
  }
}

Widget _buildSearchFields(
    dynamic _destinationController, dynamic _pickupController) {
  return Positioned(
    top: 40,
    left: 16,
    right: 16,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _pickupController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter pickup location',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 14),
            ),
            onSubmitted: (value) => _handleLocationSearch(value, 'pickup'),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Card(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _destinationController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Enter destination',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              border: InputBorder.none,
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 14),
            ),
            onSubmitted: (value) => _handleLocationSearch(value, 'destination'),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

_handleLocationSearch(String value, String s) {}


i have tried looking through github and used ai tools nothing helps and they just create new methods
